# How to change a read-only file system to a writable file system on Mac Monterey?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to manage system files in MacOS Monterey, I'm getting an error message saying the destination folder is a Read-only file system.

Is there an easy way to manage system files in MacOS Monterey?

Answer (score 1):

Since Catalina - & reinforced in subsequent OSes to be even more strict, the boot volume is read-only.
It is absolutely read-only, insomuch as it's not even a 'real' volume as far as the user is concerned. It is a virtual volume, securely locked & using a cryptographic signature to enforce that.

If you play with it, you will break it & it will no longer boot.

Your solution is to only use User locations for any & all user transactions.

From [The Eclectic Light Company - Big Sur’s Signed System Volume: added security protection](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/06/25/big-surs-signed-system-volume-added-security-protection/)

> Every file on Big Sur’s System volume now has a SHA-256 cryptographic
> hash which is stored in the file system metadata. When data is read
> from the SSV, its current hash is compared with the stored hash to
> verify that the file hasn’t been tampered with or damaged. Those
> familiar with my file integrity tools will recognise that this is
> essentially the same technique employed by them.
>
> Further hashing is used in the file system metadata itself, from the
> deepest directories up to the root node, where it’s called the seal.
> This ensures those hashes cover the entire volume, its data and
> directory structure. The seal is verified each time your Mac starts
> up, by the boot loader before the kernel is loaded, and during
> installation and update of macOS system files. If verification fails,
> startup is halted and the user prompted to re-install macOS before
> proceeding.

This article includes workarounds, but they will leave your system in an uncertain state & unless you really know why you *must* do this… don't.